# captured video sharing on facebook, twitter and email

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, video, sharing

I want to capture a video and after that share it on some social networking sites and email so i have captured video and saved that onto photo album now i don't know how can i share that captured/saved video please suggest something for this, here is my code for captured video storing..:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    // NSLog(@"dictionary info %@", info);

    if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
    {
        // Copy it to the camera roll.

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), tempFilePath);

        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        vidPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
        [vidPath retain];

        BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:vidPath atomically:NO];

        NSLog(@"Written file on path success? , %@\n", (success ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Update**

i have tried this code to generate tiny url for sharing the video but it's not working :(

```
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",vidPath];
[apiEndpoint retain];

shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                       error:nil];
[shortURL retain];
```

here i'll be able to store video on photo gallery and document directory now i want to share that so how to do that? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, as suggested by Luis in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12792851/19679):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];

NSURL *videoPathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:videoPath isDirectory:NO];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];

NSString *status = @"One step closer.";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"title":status, @"description":status};

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
                                                  URL:url 
                                           parameters:params];

[request addMultipartData:videoData
                 withName:@"source"
                     type:@"video/quicktime" 
                 filename:[videoPathURL absoluteString]];
```

**Email**

```
-(IBAction)sendmailPress:(id)sender
{

MFMailComposeViewController* Apicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if (Apicker != nil)
    {

        [Apicker setSubject:@""];

        [Apicker setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:NO];


        [Apicker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        Apicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSData *mym=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:VideoPath];

       NSLog(@"%@",mym);
        [Apicker addAttachmentData:mym mimeType:@".Extension" fileName:videoname];
[self presentModalViewController:Apicker animated:YES];
        [Apicker release];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: actually i need a global solution that works for all coz i want to share my captured video on fb,twitter and on email too...

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper, see my updated answer. Sorry, I don't know about Twitter.

Comment: +1 for your efforts thanks man :) i will try for this code for fb and email.

Comment: Hey buddy if you could please show me how to use this fb request? that  would be a great help

Comment: had already done that but if you could paste a full method for sharing pls just like you did for e-mail

Comment: i was imagining it like it will present the composer with the text like SLComposeViewController does

Comment: Video is not a part of regular twitter status like facebook, if you do need to share on twitter you can share the video url as tweet.